# MySQL query - Total all time / Total last N days

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck with the following problem:

```
+------+---------+--------+
| Date | Keyword | clicks |
+------+---------+--------+
| D 1  | kw 1    |     50 |
| D 2  | kw 1    |     23 |
| D 3  | kw 1    |     78 |
| D 4  | kw 1    |     80 |
| D 5  | kw 1    |     80 |
| D 6  | kw 1    |     11 |
| D 7  | kw 1    |    100 |
| D 3  | kw 2    |      4 |
| D 4  | kw 2    |     11 |
| D 5  | kw 2    |     67 |
| D 6  | kw 2    |     90 |
| D 7  | kw 2    |     34 |
| D 8  | kw 2    |     64 |
| D 9  | kw 2    |     25 |
| D 10 | kw 2    |     62 |
| D 11 | kw 2    |     42 |
+------+---------+--------+
```

I tried hard but I couldn't find a query that would give me this result:

```
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| Keyword | Total clicks all time | Total clicks last 3 days |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| kw 1    |                   421 |                      190 |
| kw 2    |                   398 |                      129 |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `sum()` and `select case` to get those desired # of clicks.

```
select keyword
    , sum(case when date >= now() - interval 3 day then clicks else 0 end) as Total_3_Days
    , sum(clicks) as Total_Clicks
from tableA
group by keyword
```